# How can i write all my dictionary list in a PDF?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application to be able to list customers with open fees in a PDF. The code consists of entering a spreadsheet, checking customers who have not made the payment and saving it in a dictionary, then saving it to a PDF. What is happening is that it only lists one customer in the PDF.

Here is the code below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
import openpyxl
import os

pastaApp = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def createPDF():
    # Opens the spreadsheet and obtains the status of the last payment.

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']

    lastCol = sheet.max_column

    # Checks the payment status of each customer.

    unpaidMembers = {}
    clients = []
    months = []
    emails = []
    for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
            payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if payment != 'ok':
                client = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
                email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
                month = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
                clients.append(client)
                months.append(month)
                emails.append(email)
                unpaidMembers[client] = email
                #print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Client:', client, 'Email:', email, 'Month:', month)
                print('dictionary created successfully')

    cnv = canvas.Canvas(pastaApp+"\\test.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    cnv.drawString(10, 800, "Open Fee")
    cnv.drawString(130, 800, " - Client/Month/E-mail")
    cnv.drawString(10, 780, client)
    cnv.drawString(170, 780, month)
    cnv.drawString(350, 780, email)
    cnv.save()

root = Tk()
root.title("Create PDF")

btn_createPDF = Button(root, text="Check", command=createPDF)
btn_createPDF.pack(side="left", padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a spreadsheet model: https://prnt.sc/125jdcq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code saves exactly one record:

```py
cnv.drawString(10, 780, client)
cnv.drawString(170, 780, month)
cnv.drawString(350, 780, email)
```

To save all the records, use:

```py
y = 780
for client, month, email in zip(clients, months, emails):
    cnv.drawString(10, y, client)
    cnv.drawString(170, y, month)
    cnv.drawString(350, y, email)
    y -= 20
```

*Note that my code does not cater page size.*

Comment: acw1668, thank you so much, it helped me a lot. I noticed that if there is a greater number of customers, the PDF does not expand to a second page, it is cut off.

Comment: I have already mentioned that issue at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, but even if I remove the size, it keeps cutting.